# Filter using NOT IN with more than one column

Tags: t-sql

Is there a better way to write the following query to minimize code repetition in the WHERE statement?

```
SELECT TA.*
FROM TA
JOIN TB on TA.id = TB.id
JOIN TC on TB.id =TC.id
JOIN TD on TC.id = TD.id
JOIN TE on TD.id = TE.id
WHERE TC.Name NOT IN (‘John’,’William’,’Jacob’,’Henry’,’David’)
AND TD.Name NOT IN (‘John’,’William’,’Jacob’,’Henry’,’David’)
AND TE.Name NOT IN (‘John’,’William’,’Jacob’,’Henry’,’David’)
```

Note: The filter is always the same: `NOT IN (‘John’,’William’,’Jacob’,’Henry’,’David’)`

Comment: If you have to use the same filter on more than one column than there's something wrong with your database. You should try normalizing your data.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `‘` and `’` should both be "straight single quotes": `'`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you can do something like this:

```
SELECT  TA.*
FROM TA
JOIN TB on TA.id = TB.id
JOIN TC on TB.id =TC.id
JOIN TD on TC.id = TD.id
JOIN TE on TD.id = TE.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES('John'),('William'),('Jacob'),('Henry'),('David')) V(name)
    WHERE Name IN(TC.Name, TD.Name, TE.Name)
)
```